# How do I add this windowed function as a calculated column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE TempScore.Score
ADD Ranking AS (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SumOfScores DESC))
```

This code will not work because it is a windowed function, I assume I will have to use a function to create it however I don't know how to do it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't use a Window or Aggregate Function in a Computed Column. You'll either need to create a `VIEW`, and reference that instead of your `TABLE`, or (and I don't recommend this one) create a Scaler Value Function and reference that in your Computed Column. You would be better, however, creating a `VIEW`.

Comment: Computed columns cannot reference other rows. Often times an indexed view can be substituted but that's also not going to work here. The issue is that the delete of a single row (a single one currently ranked 1) would cause the *entire* table to have to be recomputed. That's not healthy. Either the table is *big*, in which case that update is prohibitively expensive, or the table is *small* in which case computing this value on demand should perform well enough.